# node_modules directory not created when using npm install during AWS CodeBuild

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codebuild

After the CodeBuild is complete and I ssh into my environment, I can see that the server app's dependencies are installed and found in its node_modules. However in the client directory, there is no node_modules nor build directory. In the build logs, `npm install --prefix client --production` appears to run fine.

My question is almost exactly like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62545984/aws-codebuild-not-generating-build-folder-nodejs), except it is both the node_modules and the build folder.

Is there a problem with the buildspec file? Here it is (**EDIT 4**: updated)

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      # upgrade AWS CLI
      - pip install --upgrade awscli
      # install Node 12
      - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
      - apt install nodejs

  pre_build:
    commands:
      # install server dependencies
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      # install client dependencies and build static files
      - npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client

  post_build:
    commands:
      - ls -la
      - ls client -la

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```

**EDIT 1**: here's an example of what the codebuild logs show for the `npm install --prefix client`:

```
Running command npm install --prefix client --production



> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /codebuild/output/src133125934/src/client/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
```

And for the `npm run build -prefix client`:

```
[Container] 2020/07/02 00:24:06 Entering phase BUILD
[Container] 2020/07/02 00:24:06 Running command npm run build --prefix client



> client@0.1.0 build /codebuild/output/src133125934/src/client
> react-scripts build



Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.



File sizes after gzip:



  144.95 KB  build/static/js/2.d25271aa.chunk.js
  23.22 KB   build/static/css/main.fe6e5073.chunk.css
  6.38 KB    build/static/js/main.8e99a285.chunk.js
  774 B      build/static/js/runtime-main.f63e6028.js
```

**EDIT 2**: Using ls to see the directories after the build:

```
[Container] 2020/07/02 01:11:24 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2020/07/02 01:11:24 Running command ls -la
total 136
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  4096 Jul  2 01:09 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Jul  2 01:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul  2 01:09 .ebextensions
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   130 Jul  2 01:08 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root    16 Jul  2 01:08 .npmrc
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root    34 Jul  2 01:08 README.md
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root  1737 Jul  2 01:08 app.js
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul  2 01:09 bin
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   566 Jul  2 01:08 buildspec.yml
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Jul  2 01:10 client
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul  2 01:09 config
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul  2 01:09 graphql
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul  2 01:09 models
drwxr-xr-x 197 root root  4096 Jul  2 01:10 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root 63888 Jul  2 01:08 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   814 Jul  2 01:08 package.json
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul  2 01:09 routes
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul  2 01:09 services
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul  2 01:09 views




[Container] 2020/07/02 01:11:24 Running command ls client -la
total 748
drwxr-xr-x    6 root root   4096 Jul  2 01:10 .
drwxr-xr-x   12 root root   4096 Jul  2 01:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x    3 root root   4096 Jul  2 01:11 build
drwxr-xr-x 1081 root root  36864 Jul  2 01:10 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--    1 root root 699332 Jul  2 01:08 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--    1 root root   1212 Jul  2 01:08 package.json
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root   4096 Jul  2 01:09 public
drwxr-xr-x    8 root root   4096 Jul  2 01:09 src
```

**EDIT 3**: After verifying the directories are made, I ssh into the beanstalk (ec2) instance to check if they have been deployed but this is what I get:

```
$ cd /var/app/current
$ ls
app.js
bin
buildspec.yml
client
config
graphql
models
node_modules
package.json
package-lock.json
Procfile
README.md
routes
services
views

$ cd client
$ ls
package.json 
package-lock.json 
public 
src
```

The build and modules directory are not deployed into beanstalk.

Comment: Are you sure that all the files you need are in `client/build`? With the `base-directory`, `**/*` will apply to `client/build`. Also you can go to S3 and download the artifact in zip and inspect its structure to see in detail what it has.

Comment: @Marcin This is my first project using aws so correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't the files in the base-directory be static files for the website on Elastic Beanstalk? Or is it supposed to be the entire project?

Comment: I assume you use CodePipeline and CP deploys to EB? Then it should be entire project, just like you would upload the zip file yourself though EB console.

Comment: @Marcin thank you for the clarification! I checked the structures after removing the base-directory and the ``client/node_modules`` and the ``client/build`` directories are still not there. I don't know which stage causes this error; when looking at the logs, the commands ``npm install --prefix client`` and ``npm run build --prefix client`` are being run so I assume the directories are being made **somewhere**

Comment: Just remove ` base-directory: 'client/build'` for testing and troubleshooting. This will allow you to download the entire folder and inspect it. Maybe `npm install` is installing in system folders, not your local working directly?

Comment: @Marcin I edited in some logs from the CodeBuild. The directories that it shows appear to be within the proper local directory, no? Specifically ``/codebuild/output/src133125934/src/client/``...

Comment: But is `node_modules` there or still missing?

Comment: @Marcin still missing :(

Comment: What does the --production flag do? From docs "With the --production flag (or when the NODE_ENV environment variable is set to production), npm will not install modules listed in devDependencies." Maybe this could be the reason?

Comment: @Marcin There is nothing in my devDependencies at the moment, but I added it there for potential future use. Still, I have tried removing it but nothing has changed and the logs show the same amount of dependencies installed either way

Comment: Can you add after `- npm run build --prefix client` new line: `- ls -la` to show in the logs what's in the folder after the build?

Comment: @Marcin I edited in the results. This confirms the directories are in fact created but for some reason are lost when deployed to beanstalk?

Comment: Its all there. Have you removed ` base-directory: 'client/build'` from the build specs?

Comment: @Marcin Yes it has been removed, I also just edited in what it looks like when I ssh into the instance

Comment: I the new printout there is `node_modules`?

Comment: Also what about `.ebextensions`? Maybe you have some script there which deletes or overwrites your folders/files?

Comment: @Marcin the ``node_modules`` in the root directory was always fine, but the one in the client folder along with the ``build`` folder has never shown up after the build. I'll try removing the ``.ebextensions`` folder temporarily to see if anything changes. It only has a ``static-files.config`` file for setting the static files to be in ``client/build``. Could this affect it?

Comment: Not sure. At this stage, it does not hurt checking this.

Comment: @Marcin removing the .ebextensions led to no change, the directories were still not there. Could it be some kind of caching issue? Could it be a ``.gitignore`` thing? I have both ``node_module`` folderes ignored but that doesn't prevent the root one to be created.

Comment: Don't know. At this stage, it just `try-and-see` methodology of troubleshooting :-( I don't have more precised ideas at present. Sorry.

Comment: @Marcin I'll definitely try, I really appreciate your time and the help :)

Comment: No problem. Wish I could help more. Anyway, if you figure it out, please let me know. Very curious on what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the Deploy stage of the CodePipeline was taking in the Source output, not the Build output. Setting the Deploy input as the Build output fixed it!

Comment: Could you please add the code as part of this solution?