# AWS CodePipeline missing directories/files after being deployed to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

This is a more-narrowed-down problem stemming from [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62685988/node-modules-directory-not-created-when-using-npm-install-during-aws-codebuild).

Here is my buildspec.yml:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      # upgrade AWS CLI
      - pip install --upgrade awscli
      # install Node 12
      - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
      - apt install nodejs

  pre_build:
    commands:
      # install server dependencies
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      # install client dependencies and build static files
      - npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client

  post_build:
    commands:
      # FOR TESTING AND DEBUGGING
      - ls -la
      - ls client -la
      - mkdir client/TEST
      - ls client -la

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  discard-paths: no
  base-directory: '*'
```

In the post-build phase, I output directories for debugging and this is what they show:

```
[Container] 2020/07/02 02:36:15 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2020/07/02 02:36:15 Running command ls -la
total 132
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Jul  2 02:34 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Jul  2 02:34 ..
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   129 Jul  2 02:33 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root    16 Jul  2 02:33 .npmrc
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root    34 Jul  2 02:33 README.md
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root  1737 Jul  2 02:33 app.js
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul  2 02:34 bin
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   655 Jul  2 02:33 buildspec.yml
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Jul  2 02:35 client
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul  2 02:34 config
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul  2 02:34 graphql
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul  2 02:34 models
drwxr-xr-x 197 root root  4096 Jul  2 02:34 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root 63888 Jul  2 02:33 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   814 Jul  2 02:33 package.json
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul  2 02:34 routes
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul  2 02:34 services
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul  2 02:34 views




[Container] 2020/07/02 02:36:15 Running command ls client -la
total 748
drwxr-xr-x    6 root root   4096 Jul  2 02:35 .
drwxr-xr-x   11 root root   4096 Jul  2 02:34 ..
drwxr-xr-x    3 root root   4096 Jul  2 02:36 build
drwxr-xr-x 1081 root root  36864 Jul  2 02:35 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--    1 root root 699332 Jul  2 02:33 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--    1 root root   1212 Jul  2 02:33 package.json
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root   4096 Jul  2 02:34 public
drwxr-xr-x    8 root root   4096 Jul  2 02:34 src



[Container] 2020/07/02 02:36:15 Running command mkdir client/TEST



[Container] 2020/07/02 02:36:15 Running command ls client -la
total 752
drwxr-xr-x    7 root root   4096 Jul  2 02:36 .
drwxr-xr-x   11 root root   4096 Jul  2 02:34 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root   4096 Jul  2 02:36 TEST
drwxr-xr-x    3 root root   4096 Jul  2 02:36 build
drwxr-xr-x 1081 root root  36864 Jul  2 02:35 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--    1 root root 699332 Jul  2 02:33 package-lock.json
-rw-rw-r--    1 root root   1212 Jul  2 02:33 package.json
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root   4096 Jul  2 02:34 public
drwxr-xr-x    8 root root   4096 Jul  2 02:34 src




[Container] 2020/07/02 02:36:15 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2020/07/02 02:36:15 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2020/07/02 02:36:15 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2020/07/02 02:36:15 Phase context status code:  Message:
```

Which shows that `client/build`, `client/node_modules`, and a test directory `client/TEST` were all created during the CodeBuild. However when I go to the Beanstalk environment I get the error:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/app/current/client/build/index.html'
```

When I ssh into Beanstalk and check the `/var/app/current/` directory, the `node_modules` in the root directory was successfully built. However, the `client/build`, `client/node_modules`, and `client/TEST` are all **missing**:

```
$ cd /var/app/current
$ ls
app.js  buildspec.yml  config  models  package.json  Procfile  routes  views
bin  client  graphql  node_modules  package-lock.json  README.md  services
$ cd client
$ ls
package.json package-lock.json public src
```

This indicates to me that something messed up in the Deploy stage of the CodePipeline, or maybe the `artifacts` section of the `buildspec.yml`. I have been stuck on this issue for so long and have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: Hi. Again, to double check. The folders are also missing from the deployment package? When you go to EB console then to `Application Versions` and download the zip produced by CP, it will not have the needed files?

Comment: @Marcin I don't think I can download the zip from CodePipeline since the output is piped directly into Beanstalk. When I go to ``Application Versions``, I can't download any .zips because they are all ``application/octet-stream`` files.

Comment: When you setup CP, you should specify a bucket or let CP create one for you. You can go to the S3 bucket in this case, and inspect there. The zip will have some strange name and probably no extension.

Comment: @Marcin ah yes I have seen it in the S3 bucket but how do I download it as a zip if there is no extension? Firefox just says to download it as an octet-stream.

Comment: If you press `Download` it does not prompt to download it? Also can try renaming by adding the zip extension.

Comment: @Marcin Renaming it worked, thanks! The directories aren't there but the strange part is that neither is the root ``node_modules``. But in the Beanstalk instance, it is there.

Comment: Also during EB deployment, the currently being deployed application will be in `/var/app/staging`, not `/var/app/current`. Can inspect there as well. But if the zip does not have it, it means that CB is somehow not adding it. Intresting.

Comment: For the deploy stage, what is the source provider? Is it CB? Maybe your deploy stage gets source from the "source stage", skipping CB outcome?

Comment: @Marcin There is no ``staging`` directory in my ``/var/app/``. But yes, I agree that it's definitely something weird with CB.

Comment: Can you double check the CP setup. If Deploy fetches outcome  from source stage, rather then from build stage, it could explain why everything is missing.

Comment: @Marcin AH this could be the issue! For input artifact in Deploy, it says SourceArtifact, but there is no alternative when I click it. How could I change it?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to change to CB. Otherwise outcome of CB is not used. Check CB setup. maybe you set it up as having no artifacts?

Comment: @Marcin setting a build output did in fact change what was on the server, but the ``/var/app/current`` directory now appears to be the root ``node_module`` extracted. Any ideas why that is? Actually it was every folder at the root extracted.

Comment: @Marcin Nevermind i fixed it. Everything is good now, THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked out. If you don't mind I will also provide answer with some extra info.

Comment: @Marcin All good with me :)

Comment: Thanks. If my help was useful, acceptance of my answer would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comments.

To deploy to ElasticBeanstalk, CodePipepine is using  [Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-pipeline-structure.html) provider in a `Deploy` action. As part of setting up this action, `input artifacts` need to be specified.

The issue was that the **input artifacts** were set to use `Source` action, rather then the `CodeBuild` action.

**The solution was** to adjust the setting of the the `Deploy` action to use the `CodeBuild` artifacts, instead of Source artifacts.